# SQL - Convert Rows to Columns, group data and count rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Current Scenario:

I have the following source data table (TABLE1):

```
SOURCEDATE      FILENAME  UNIQUE_ROW
--------------  --------  ----------
20140704232250  FILE1     ABCDEF10
20140704232250  FILE2     ABCDEF11
20140704232250  FILE3     ABCDEF12
20140704232250  FILE4     ABCDEF13
20140704232250  FILE1     ABCDEF10
20140704232250  FILE2     ABCDEF11
20140704232250  FILE3     ABCDEF12
20140704232250  FILE4     ABCDEF13
20140703232250  FILE1     ABCDEF14
20140703232250  FILE3     ABCDEF15
20140703232250  FILE1     ABCDEF14
20140703232250  FILE3     ABCDEF15
20140702232250  FILE2     ABCDEF16
20140702232250  FILE3     ABCDEF17
20140702232250  FILE4     ABCDEF18
20140701232250  FILE1     ABCDEF19
20140701232250  FILE5     ABCDEF20
20140630232250  FILE2     ABCDEF21
20140630232250  FILE3     ABCDEF22
20140629232250  FILE1     ABCDEF23
20140629232250  FILE4     ABCDEF24
20140629232250  FILE5     ABCDEF25
20140629232250  FILE6     ABCDEF26
20140629232250  FILE1     ABCDEF23
20140629232250  FILE4     ABCDEF24
20140629232250  FILE5     ABCDEF25
20140629232250  FILE6     ABCDEF26
```

Date is in the YYYYMMDDHH24MISS format at the moment. I am looking to convert the above rows and columns to be in the following format and inserted into TABLE2:

```
SOURCEDATE  FILE1  FILE2  FILE3  FILE4  FILE5  FILE6
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
04-07-2014    2      2      2      2      0      0
03-07-2014    2      0      2      0      0      0
02-07-2014    0      1      1      1      0      0
01-07-2014    1      0      0      0      1      0
30-06-2014    0      1      1      0      0      0
29-06-2014    2      0      0      2      2      2
```

In other words, I want the source data to be grouped by date and filename and a count done. If a particular file record does not exist then insert a 0 value to Table2.

I have basic SQL knowledge but this is currently beyond my expertise. I have been able to create a table that can do the count of files per date but cannot format the table based on the above requirements. My current SQL code is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS
   select
      to_char(TO_DATE(SOURCEDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS S_DATE,
      filename,
      count(*) as RECORD_COUNT 
   from TABLE1
   group by SOURCEDATE, filename
   order by SOURCEDATE DESC;
```

This gives me the following table:

```
S_DATE      FILENAME  RECORD_COUNT
----------  --------  ------------
04-07-2014  FILE1           2
04-07-2014  FILE2           2
04-07-2014  FILE3           2
04-07-2014  FILE4           2
03-07-2014  FILE1           2
03-07-2014  FILE3           2
02-07-2014  FILE2           1
02-07-2014  FILE3           1
02-07-2014  FILE4           1
01-07-2014  FILE1           1
01-07-2014  FILE5           1
30-06-2014  FILE2           1
30-06-2014  FILE3           1
29-06-2014  FILE1           2
29-06-2014  FILE4           2
29-06-2014  FILE5           2
29-06-2014  FILE6           2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For older version of oracles (10g) you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS
  SELECT
     TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sourcedate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS s_date,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file1,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file2,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file3,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file4,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file5,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file6
  FROM TABLE1
  or GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sourcedate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

For oracle 11G, you can use PIVOT function :

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS
WITH MY_TAB AS
(SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sourcedate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS s_date,
FILENAME FROM TABLE1
)
select *
from MY_TAB
pivot
(
  COUNT(FILENAME)
  for FILENAME in ('FILE1', 'FILE2', 'FILE3','FILE4','FILE5','FILE6')
) piv;
```

**[FIDDLE HERE for 11G](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8370/1)**

**[FIDDLE HERE FOR 10G and 11G](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94cff/1)**

Comment: Wow, that (first option) is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS
  SELECT
     TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sourcedate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS s_date,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file1,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file2,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file3,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file4,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file5,
     SUM(CASE WHEN filename='FILE6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS file6
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY SOURCEDATE;
```

Since you are creating a table, I am quite confident the number of distinct filename values is known and fixed, so there is no need to do a cross join.

No real need to order the data either, if you are inserting it into a table. Don't rely on the physical order of the data. Order it when you fetch it, explicitly.